# $g \in L^1_{loc}(G), \ \psi \in C_{00}^\infty(G) \Rightarrow g\psi$ Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $G\subseteq \mathbb R^d,\ g \in L^1_{loc}(G), \ \psi \in C_{00}^\infty(G)$.

$L^1_{loc}(G)$ is the set of all locally integrable functions in $G$ and $C_{00}^\infty(G)$ is the set of all $C^{\infty}$ with compact support $\subseteq G$.

> I have two questions:

Why is $g\psi$ integrable on $G$ with respect to $\lambda_d$?

Why is $\int_{G}(g\psi)\phi=0$ for all $\phi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^d)$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $K$ be the support of $\psi$. Then $\psi(x)=0$ for $x \notin K$ so $\int |g \psi|d\lambda_{d}=\int_K |g \psi|d\lambda_{d} \leq C\int_K |g |d\lambda_{d}$ where $C$ is the supremum of $|\psi|$ on $K$. Hence $g\psi$ is intgrable.

With the given hypothesis there is no reason why $\int g \phi \psi=0$: take $g=1$ and $\phi =\psi$.

EDIT based on OP's comment: if you assume that $\int g\psi d\lambda_d=0$ for all $\psi \in C_{00}^{\infty}(G)$ then $\int g\psi \phi d\lambda_d=0$ simply because $\phi \psi \in C_{00}^{\infty}(G)$.

Comment: I forgot to mention it.$g$ is such that $\int_G g\psi d\lambda_d=0 \ \forall \psi \in C_{00}^\infty(G)$

Comment: @user700332 I have edited my answer.